# how to create a dynamic menu with font icons fetch from database from library using code ingnitor anchor tag

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hi am trying to create a dynamic menu from my database. have seen a lot of examples but i dont seem to understand them. this is what my database looks like

This was my current code:

```php
$html_out .="\t\t\t".'<li><a href='.$url.' data-toggle=pills class=2><i class='.$icon.' aria-hidden=true></i><span>'.$title.'</span></a><li>';
```

Comment: $html_out .="\t\t\t".'<li><a href='.$url.' data-toggle=pills class=2><i class='.$icon.' aria-hidden=true></i><span>'.$title.'</span></a><li>'; this was my current code

Comment: You may click "edit" above to edit the actual text of your post.

Answer (score 0):

```
$html_out .="\t\t\t".'<li><a href='.$url.' data-toggle=pills class=2><i class='.$icon.' aria-hidden=true></i><span>'.$title.'</span></a><li>';
```